# angular 4: should I use plain html or sub component within ngfor: what's best practice

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have to display vehicle list using ngFor
Either I use plain html like this -

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="list-item" *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles" (click)="getSingleVehicleData(vehicle)">
        <div class="at-tooltip data-type-icon">
        <span class="icon-wrapper">
        <i class="icon-light-color">
        </i>
    </span>
</div>
```

OR I can use sub component like this-

```
<div class="list">
    <app-vehicle-list-item class="list-item"
        *ngFor="let vehicleItem of vehicles"
        [vehicleItem]="vehicleItem">
    </app-vehicle-list-item>
</div>
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: use a sub component as the instance will be separate and the logics for each vehicle will be inside the component

Comment: Plain HTML. An ngFor inside of a component will just keep displaying the same component over and over again.

Comment: Doesn't really matter either way.... and it depends on the larger structure of your app, like how-often your going to reuse that component, and wheather there is much logic in the ts file....

Comment: Also, can you sort those code snippets out?!!!

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how much your going to reuse it- if this is a one-off component, then it's sort of overkill to create another inner-component. But if your using it throughout your app, then I'd definitely make it a sub-component.

It would also depend on whether there's much `vehicle`-specific logic that would be cleaner to separate out, rather than have it just shoved into the parent component.

Alternatively...:

- Consider using nested components instead. [Read more here](https://appendto.com/2016/09/building-nested-components-using-angular-2/).
- Have a read of [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-style-guide/issues/5) talking about component directory structures

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using sub component, because it creates seperate instance for each item of array.

and it will be more useful when you are implementing things like toggle panel.
If you you sub component then it will be very easy to handle toggle because each item has its own instance.

Answer (score 0):

A 'half-way' step to a full component is to use `ngTemplateOutlet` with context. That way you can have the same template in use in several places.

```
<div *ngFor="vehicle in vehicles">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate; context:vehicle"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #myTemplate let-vehicle="vehicle">
  <span>{{vehicle}}</span>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Do we have any performance difference in both cases?
I remember, in Angular 1.x days, using a directive inside repeater was a bad practice.

Comment: I haven't got any performance tests, but my understanding is that ngFor uses implicit templates by default, so setting an explicit template shouldn't worsen performance by much. Equally, instantiating multiple component instances (with the resultant re-rendering) does sound like it could be a performance bottleneck - though I don't know if angular 2+ does anything to mitigate this (and how much trackBy helps here).